# Converting from TIFF to PNG without PIL

Tags: python, png, tiff, image-conversion

Can someone please suggest a good way to convert from TIFF to PNG in python without using PIL? PIL seems to be the most suggested way to do this, but it cannot understand the data format of my files. When I try to use PIL, I get an unidentified image error:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('path/to/dir/my_file.tiff')
```

`PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'my_file.tiff'`

As I understand it, this it because these are 64 bit TIFF files, which PIL cannot understand. So, can anyone suggest another way that I can convert these images to PNGs?

Comment: I know you said without PIL, but can you show the code that threw that PIL error?

Comment: @MatíasSanturio I edited the question with some code.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of a tiff image you can't open?

Comment: **ImageMagick** in the Terminal, `magick INPUT.TIF OUTPUT.PNG` or with `wand` in Python.